# VB - Calculation always returns a 0

Tags: vb.net

When I change two strings to a double, then subtract them, the answer is always 0. does anyone know a way to fix this?

```
    Dim TotalCashNum As Double
    Dim InsertCoinNum As Double
    Dim NewTotalCash As Double

    InsertCoinsTextBox.Text = Convert.ToDouble(InsertCoinNum)
    TotalCash.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TotalCashNum)
    NewTotalCash = TotalCashNum - InsertCoinNum
    MsgBox(NewTotalCash)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you turn Option Strict On in your project settings. It will make a lot of mistakes like this one more visible.

Comment: you have the assignment backwards.

Comment: Why are you calling `Convert.ToDouble` _on a variable of type Double_?  It's already a Double!  +1 for Option Strict On

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
InsertCoinsTextBox.Text = Convert.ToDouble(InsertCoinNum)
TotalCash.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TotalCashNum)
```

Should be

```
InsertCoinNum = CDbl(InsertCoinsTextBox.Text )
TotalCashNum = CDbl(TotalCash.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the values of the textbox to the variables wrong.

It should be:

```
Dim TotalCashNum As Double
Dim InsertCoinNum As Double
Dim NewTotalCash As Double

InsertCoinNum = CDbl(InsertCoinsTextBox.Text )
TotalCashNum = CDbl(TotalCash.Text)
NewTotalCash = TotalCashNum - InsertCoinNum
```